# How to intercept data sent to a USB flash drive in the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, usb, storage, driver

Where in the Linux kernel source code can I find the function(s) that deal with sending data to a USB flash drive? By "data", I mean the actual file contents. For example, when I drag and drop "Report.docx" to the USB thumb drive, I need to be able to intercept this data to the point where I could modify the contents of the file before it is written to the USB thumb drive.

I understand that the USB storage module (`drivers/usb/storage`) is where USB mass storage devices like thumb drives are handled, but I failed to find the right place to look. I looked around `transfer.c` but my debugging attempts just show the functions get called whether or not I'm transferring any files. Also, from my understanding, everything is done with URBs and I'm not clear on how to deal with those. Am I looking in the right place?

For the purposes of my project, I need to modify the driver (not using any third-party libraries or user-space code). I am working with Linux 3.12.0.

Comment: Linux disk access uses a lot of layers.  The filesystem knows nothing about USB flash drives.  The USB storage driver knows nothing about files.

Comment: Your best option is to make an overlay filesystem, and have the user drag their file into there.  This can be accomplished by changing where the USB drive gets mounted, and then mounting your overlay in the location the user expects to use.

Comment: For example, have a look at [UnionFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnionFS)

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert in usb subsystem, but I would start by looking at
drivers/usb/storage/transport.c::usb_stor_bulk_transfer_buf()

Comment: As you might note from the long-existing comments, this is unlikely to be a very efficient way to go about the mentioned goal of "modifying the contents of the file"